# (LWJGL) Pixel Unpack Buffer Object is Disabled? (glTextImage2D)

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, frame-buffer

I am trying to create a render target for my game so that I can re-render at a different screen size. But I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Pixel Unpack Buffer Object is disabled
```

Here is the source code for my Render method:

```
    // clear screen
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Start FBO Rendering Code
    // The framebuffer, which regroups 0, 1, or more textures, and 0 or 1 depth buffer.
    int FramebufferName = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

    // The texture we're going to render to
    int renderedTexture = glGenTextures();

    // "Bind" the newly created texture : all future texture functions will modify this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

    // Give an empty image to OpenGL ( the last "0" )
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // Poor filtering. Needed !
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Set "renderedTexture" as our colour attachement #0
    GL32.glFramebufferTexture(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

    // Set the list of draw buffers.
    IntBuffer drawBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(20 * 20);
    GL20.glDrawBuffers(drawBuffer);

    // Always check that our framebuffer is ok
    if(GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        System.out.println("Framebuffer was not created successfully! Exiting!");
        return;
    }



    // Resets the current viewport
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, scaleWidth*scale, scaleHeight*scale);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    // let subsystem paint
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.frameRendering();
    }



    // update window contents
    Display.update();
```

It is crashing on this line:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

I am not really sure why it is crashing and looking around I have not been able to find out why. Any help or insight would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The last input in the function is the problem. If you look at the lwjgl source code you can see that it uses it as an offset (used with PBOs). To actually pass no data use a 'null' instead.